# How can I save the grep output of a curl to a variable and don't log it to the console?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, grep, cgi

I have a shell script (called by apache cgi) that should curl and grep the result to check the health of a server. That's what I've got so far.

```
printf "Content-type: text/html\n"
PAGE="$(curl -v -u http://targetserver/xmlgatewayauth/login)"
CRES="$($PAGE|grep "login";)"
echo $CRES;
```

If I run the script in Linux as a shell the output is:

```
...
< Location: login_success.jsp
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 15 Oct 2018 08:42:39 GMT
...
```

but if I call the script via CGI from the browser - the result is empty.
I've tested the CGI Script with a static output and it worked. (Hello World).

The problem is: 
I don't want the script to output anything but the variable "CRES". But it outputs the whole curl (grep)(not the variable) to the console and doesnt ouput the variable to the website.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `CRES=$(curl ... | grep "login")`

Comment: @MarkSetchell still outputs everything from grep

Comment: What Mark posted is a most probably a way to combine line 2 and 3 above into a single line. I'm pretty sure, the problem you are facing is caused by the misplacement of line 1.

Comment: You seem to be missing a shebang as your first line, something like `#!/bin/bash`. Did you make your script executable with `chmod +x YourScriptName`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing line 1 before the other lines. So change the order to this:

```
PAGE="$(curl -v -u http://targetserver/xmlgatewayauth/login)"
CRES="$($PAGE|grep "login";)"
echo $CRES;
printf "Content-type: text/html\n"
```

or

```
PAGE="$(curl -v -u http://targetserver/xmlgatewayauth/login)"
CRES="$($PAGE|grep "login";)"
printf "Content-type: text/html\n"
echo $CRES;
```